# How to clear a number input field on focus

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to create a number input field in React, where once the user clicks in the input, the initial value clears. Now there seems to be solutions with text inputs, but I have not seen this done with number inputs. Anytime I've tried to solve this problem, I always get 'a component is changing a controlled input of type number to be uncontrolled.' Any suggestions? Here is a quick demo
[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-breeze-5hb3q?file=/src/App.tsx:163-253)

Comment: That's not exactly "standard" behavior, is it?  Just set it to a sensible default value.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing a text input is just setting it's value to an empty string. You can actually do this with a number input as well. (In fact, the value you are storing is already a string, although you have typed it as `number | undefined`).

```js
onFocus={() => setCount("")}
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-framework-dkckc?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the number input to a particular value you need to specify it as an argument while calling the function 'SetCount()', if you wanted the default value to be 4 for example:

```
onFocus={() => setCount(4)}
```

while now you are just calling it with undefined as an argument:

```
onFocus={() => setCount(undefined)}
```

The code doesn't work at the moment beacouse you are trying to set the content of an input field as undefined